# (Updated)How to force a browser window to seems like a desktop app window?

Tags: python, electron, desktop

Dears,

I'm using Electron and Python to deploy desktop apps. However, I'm wondering if I can exclude the Electron part of this project. I want just put some settings in a js file or something like that to imitate the appearance of a desktop window. In this approach, my user will just need Firefox or Chrome installed to use the app (and the python core that I'm shipping). Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Maybe this is of interest but there is still an initial download (think: Adobe AIR or Director ShockMachine) https://medium.com/dailyjs/put-your-electron-app-on-a-diet-with-electrino-c7ffdf1d6297

Comment: I'm trying neutralino to replace Electron. It's interesting but it's a buggy platform yet. Electrino seems good, but is in too initial stage, right?